# Get latest mysql records without updating page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that prints the records from an mysql database table. But is there a way to have it update automatically, so that if new records are inserted into the table while the user is viewing the page, the newly inserted records will show up (without the user refreshing the page)?

Comment: ajax, poll the server on some schedule checking for new records.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax : 
here's an example of using ajax with mysql :
[Ajax Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

or you can use JQuery ajax which is the easiest:
[JQuery Ajax Example](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107)

Comment: I understand that will show the initial contents of the table, but will it update in "real time" if the table updates?

Comment: @Max if you read the example you'll find the answer , and also you can find tons and tons of example of ajax , I recommend you do it with JQuery Ajax it is easy and no need to write the whole implementation of Ajax

Answer (score 0):

In short words: of course, it is possible by AJAX (asynchronous requests). Just type this name into Google and find a plenty of websites/tutorials how to use it.

There is in fact two issues to solve:

1. Asynchronous request checking new records
2. Updating the DOM (HTML tags representation of website)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few keywords and resources that should lead you down the right path, or at least a more specific question in the future!

- [setInterval()](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/#alertTimerButton)
- [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)
- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - One of many (my
  favorite) JavaScript libraries that will make using AJAX a lot
  easier.
- [Populating Table Data using jQuery](http://mytechworld.officeacuity.com/?p=457)
- [A simple way to populate a table using AJAX](http://www.arunraj.co.in/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7%3apopulate-table-using-ajax&catid=4%3ajavascript&Itemid=9)